# How to drag and position a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three div in a page I want user can reposision div as the want

```
<div class="A"></div>
<div class="B"></div>
<div class="C"></div>
```

Originally it is ordered ABC.
User can reposition div  as CBA, CAB as  user want 
How to do this.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/ see this

Comment: short [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/26q2M/)

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid . Try this up

Comment: when I am going next page and coming back it is in original condition is it possible to save it

Comment: you need to use cookies for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML :**

```
<div class="sortable">
     <div class="A"></div>
     <div class="B"></div>
     <div class="C"></div>
</div>
```

**Jquery :**

```
 <script>
     $(function() {
       $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
       $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
     });
</script>
```

Add these jquery files to your code :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can chain it. 
$( "#sortable" ).sortable().disableSelection();
One of the powers of jquery :)